# measuring electricity on a shared circuit

Tags: electrical

I live in a flat above a business and my utilities are all shared with 
the business. I need to measure my electricity usage so I can reimburse the business. I do not need to measure the gas. Can I plug in or install
one meter to measure all my usage? Do I need to put a power use meter on each used socket and ad up the numbers on all these socket meters?
Thanks

Comment: In many parts of the US this is not a legal solution. I get the impression that you are not in the US though. I would check with your building authorities if this is even an option for you.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: I would say that determining how to divide the bill is the landlord's problem, not yours.

Comment: Tenants charged for electricity are required to have a separate meter and breaker panel that is accessible to them at all times. This is how every multi-family dwelling is built here in the US anyway. Without separate metering your landlord will have to settle for a flat-rate payment included with your rent. Heat and electric is included in the rent for apartments that have not had the services separated like old houses with rooms to rent. If your landlord has a year's worth of electric bills you could help them pay for any increase in use. This would be easier than trying to meter your usage.

Comment: This is an absurd arrangement.  I would be frightened in this situation for myriad reasons.  The bottom line is, though, if this landlord wants an absurd arrangement, he/she needs to be the one to calculate this stuff.

Comment: OP wants to work this out with the business in a mutually consenting arrangement.   That is legal, because, it's consensual.  It won't hold up if landlord and tenant start using the force of law against each other, but he wouldn't be able to clawback payments already made.  You're evicted anyway at that point.  Maybe not in rent control areas, but they can find other ways to evict legally or by trickery.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a home energy meter. These are available with a clamp-on current meter and wireless remote display.

There are several details missing from your question.

1. What country you are in.
2. Where the fuseboard is. If you are sharing a fuseboard with the business than the situation becomes more difficult as you would have to monitor each of the lighting, socket, cooker, water heater, etc., circuits individually. If you have a fuseboard for your flat then you just have to monitor the incoming cable.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I would say this not legal anywhere in the world. If the electricity is provided to a unit, its for the unit. This is fire regulation rules basically used all over the world.

The only way really, is to find the source cable of the power in the flat. I assume it is one, 10mm core cable that comes out from the main distribution board and goes to another distribution board? But that is wish full thinking. I bet, the source in your flat, are various cables coming out of the main distribution board, each with its own circuit breaker, because thats the legal and proper way of doing it if the DB are not split.

I can only advise, to tally up your devices and create a reach out bill. Or use your neighbours bill, or find online resources for your areas average home usage, for the reach out estimate and adjust the total upwards accordingly (what ever you think is fair) Then yearly you apply reach out increases as per your energy bill unit prices, price increases.

Your other alternative is to use "Transistors" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Scott, there is a simple solution to your question. Use a "Kill A Watt" usage meter. Example = "P3 International P4460 Kill A Watt EZ Electricity Usage Monitor." You'll find this one on Google.  There are a number of different models but they all do the same and are inexpensive (less than $30 US). Plug your appliances into it to gather the info you need to calculate specific use, averages, as well as cost. For larger items (shared air conditioning for example) - work out an average use and negotiate for a % of the monthly bill. I've done this in past; hope it helps.  John